# Ruby grpc perpetual streams

Tags: ruby, grpc

I have a gRPC server written in c# that sends non stops ticker values.  A client in c# works fine, the ruby code however does not work with the server saying "Lost connection with client".

My ruby client follows the gRPC tutorial:

```
def get_bbo

    subscription = MarketSubscriptionMessage.new(
        ip_address: "not_needed",
        port: 0,
        major: "BTC",
        minor: "USDT",
        market_feed: 5,
        market_type: 0,
        frequency: 5
    )
    
    resps = @stub.get_bbo(subscription)
    resps.each do |r|
        pp r
    end
end
```

The message is received by the server and it starts sending messages back, but none reach the client as the client seems to exit and close the communication.

resps is an enumerator, but it has no size. What am I doing wrong?

Kind of lost and not much documentation on ruby grpc.

Comment: P.S.: Calling a non stream message works fine

Comment: I'd say this question needs way more context than it has now: what is `@stub` here, what's the different between streamed and non-streamed messages (code-wise), maybe even "how does working C# client look like?" (what are the principal differences with the Ruby one) etc... Now it's quite hard to say anything meaningful.

Comment: Konstantin, thanks for your reply.  I'm just implementing exactly what the gRPC basic tutorial from Google describes: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/ruby/basics/. @stub is defined in the initialize method and is \@stub = ExchangeAPI::Stub.new('192.168.10.15', :this_channel_is_insecure).  Stream messages receive a stream of data and non-stream messages receive a single response as defined by the service rpc

Comment: This is the rpc definition:     rpc GetBBO(MarketSubscriptionMessage) returns (stream BBOMessage) {}

Comment: It is worth adding the link to particular documentation sections to the post itself. WRT the question itself: if it works for non-stream API but not for the stream one, there might be subtle differences in Ruby and C# clients implementations. I'm afraid you will have to dig deeper than just a basic tutorial: for example, add some server-side "interceptor" (gRPC name for middleware) to log the inbound requests and compare C# client's stream requests with the Ruby ones for any discrepancies.

Comment: Again, thanks for you advice.  I'll do some more digging to see if I find the problem.  If maybe you (or someone) has a client/server gRPC fully implemented in ruby with the server continuously streaming data without ever ending and the client consuming this endless stream, it would also be very helpful.